# How to determine if any of the background process is done in shell and their elapsed time?

Tags: shell, parallel-processing

I have 8 background processes (also shell script) running in parallel, I name them `run1.sh,` `run2.sh` ... So the main process looks like the following:

```
#main.sh
./run1.sh &
./run2.sh &
./run3.sh &
...
./run8.sh &
```

I want to determine if each of these 8 process is finished and calculate how much time each process elapsed when it is done. So running `run1.sh` first doesn't guarantee that it will finish first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I did something similar, I saved the process id's in an array:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a pids

idx=0
while test $idx -lt 4; do
  ./run.sh &
  pids[$idx]=$!
  idx=$(($idx+1))
done
```

You could also set up other arrays to save the start time or whatever other information you need to track.  Then set up another loop to check for processes that have finished.  This loop would be changed depending on your exit conditions.

```
done=0
while test $done -lt 4; do
  idx=0
  while test $idx -lt 4; do
    pid=${pids[$idx]}
    if [[ $pid -ne 0 ]]; then
      kill -0 $pid
      if [[ $rc -ne 0 ]]; then
        $pids[$idx]=0  # completed.
        done=$((done+1)
      fi
    fi
  done
  sleep 1
done
```

Comment: This code requires array support, which may not be available in all shells (the question is only tagged `shell`).

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
#main.sh
time ./run1.sh &
time ./run2.sh &
time ./run3.sh &
...
time ./run8.sh &
wait
echo "Done"
```